# How to get null column when condition doesn't apply with multiple rows results

Tags: mysql, sql

I am having a hard time trying to figure out how to get the follow query result:

Let me show you the table structure and the query I am using. I think am close to get it right but I need some help figuring out what is wrong:

Here are the tables I have:

```
CREATE TABLE `manager` (
  `man_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `man_firtname` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `man_lastname` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`man_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

man_id  man_firtname    man_lastname
1       Albert          Einstein

CREATE TABLE `orders` (
  `ord_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `ord_orderno` varchar(12) NOT NULL,
  `ord_man_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `ord_total` decimal(11,0) NOT NULL,
  `ord_code` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ord_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

ord_id  ord_orderno ord_man_id  ord_total   ord_code
1       ABCDE       1           160         FFFBBB


CREATE TABLE `orders_items` (
  `ori_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `ori_ord_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `ori_item_code` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `ori_name` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  `ori_desc` varchar(80) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ori_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


ori_id  ori_ord_id  ori_item_code   ori_name    ori_desc
1       1           JO123           JohnyT      This is a test description
2       1           KK234           SprayC      Spray test description


CREATE TABLE `proda` (
  `pra_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `pra_code` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `pra_name` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`pra_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


pra_id  pra_code    pra_name
1       JO123       JohnyT


CREATE TABLE `prodb` (
  `prb_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `prb_code` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `prb_name` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`prb_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


prb_id  prb_code    prb_name
1       KK234       SprayC

CREATE TABLE `special` (
  `spe_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `spe_man_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `spe_code` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`spe_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


spe_id  spe_man_id  spe_code    spe_item_code
1       1           FFFBBB      JO123
```

This is the query I have:

```
SELECT 
    tbl1.ord_id, 
    UPPER(tbl1.ord_orderno) As ord_orderno, 
    tbl1.ord_total, 
    tbl1.ord_code, 
    tbl2.ori_id,
    tbl2.ori_item_code,
    tbl3.pra_name,
    tbl4.prb_name
  FROM
    orders tbl1
  JOIN
    orders_items tbl2
  ON
    tbl1.ord_id=tbl2.ori_ord_id
  LEFT JOIN
    proda tbl3
  ON
    tbl2.ori_item_code=tbl3.pra_code
  LEFT JOIN
    prodb tbl4
  ON
    tbl2.ori_item_code=tbl4.prb_code
  JOIN
    special tbl5
  ON
    tbl1.ord_code=tbl5.spe_code
  WHERE 
       tbl1.ord_code IN (SELECT spe_code FROM special JOIN manager ON man_id=1) 
  AND
        tbl1.ord_id=1;
```

And this is the result I get:

```
ord_id  ord_orderno ord_total   ord_code    ori_id  ori_item_code   pra_name    prb_name
1       ABCDE       160         FFFBBB      1       JO123           JohnyT  
1       ABCDE       160         FFFBBB      2       KK234           SprayC
```

What I am trying to get instead?

```
ord_id  ord_orderno ord_total   ord_code    ori_id  ori_item_code   pra_name    prb_name
1       ABCDE       160         FFFBBB      1       JO123           JohnyT  
1       ABCDE       160         NULL        2       KK234           SprayC
```

Basically, the ord_code should only show when there is a match in the special table, otherwise it should be null. Anyone has any idea on what I am doing wrong? Thank you so much

Comment: Probably nothing to do with your problem but you are trying to insert 4 values to special (which only has 3 columns)

Comment: good eyes, special has 4 columns, just a type when I wrote the sample :(

Comment: What's the point of the `JOIN` in `(SELECT spe_code FROM special JOIN manager ON man_id=1)`? It doesn't specify a relationship between the tables.

Comment: The tables are used by multiple managers. Therefore, only the right manager (e.g. man_id) user is authorized to retrieve the results for a given order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `tbl5.spe_code` instead of `tbl1.ord_code` in the `SELECT` list. When there's no match, the `LEFT JOIN` will return `NULL` for all the columns in the `special` table.

You also need to change the columns you're using in the join with `special`. it should be `tbl2.ori_item_code = tbl5.spe_item_code`.

And you need to use `LEFT JOIN` with the `special` table in order to get non-matching rows.

```
SELECT 
    tbl1.ord_id, 
    UPPER(tbl1.ord_orderno) As ord_orderno, 
    tbl1.ord_total, 
    tbl5.spe_code, 
    tbl2.ori_id,
    tbl2.ori_item_code,
    tbl3.pra_name,
    tbl4.prb_name
  FROM
    orders tbl1
  JOIN
    orders_items tbl2
  ON
    tbl1.ord_id=tbl2.ori_ord_id
  LEFT JOIN
    proda tbl3
  ON
    tbl2.ori_item_code=tbl3.pra_code
  LEFT JOIN
    prodb tbl4
  ON
    tbl2.ori_item_code=tbl4.prb_code
  LEFT JOIN
    special tbl5
  ON
    tbl2.ori_item_code=tbl5.spe_item_code
  WHERE 
       tbl1.ord_code IN (SELECT spe_code FROM special JOIN manager ON man_id=1) 
  AND
        tbl1.ord_id=1;
```

[DEMO](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/5qKFthAoAFTynVE5uVLnhZ/1)

Comment: Thanks Barmar for your feedback, do you mean something like this: SELECT 
    tbl1.ord_id, 
    UPPER(tbl1.ord_orderno) As ord_orderno, 
    tbl1.ord_total, 
    tbl5.spe_code, 
    tbl2.ori_id,
    tbl2.ori_item_code,
    tbl3.pra_name,
    tbl4.prb_name
  FROM
    orders tbl1
   This still give me  FFFBBB   for both rows :(

Comment: It will only show `NULL` if there's no match between `orders.ord_code` and `special.spe_code`. But there IS a match, since both tables have `FFFBBB`.

Comment: `WHERE tbl1.ord_code IN (SELECT spe_code FROM special JOIN manager ON man_id=1)` guarantees that there will be a match between the tables.

Comment: I saved your data in db-fiddle: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/5qKFthAoAFTynVE5uVLnhZ/0

Comment: Thanks again @Barmar for your help. However, your query does not give the output I originally specified on my questions. The thing is that FFFBBB should only be in one row and not on both rows regardless of having that value in the orders table. The orders items has two rows. One of the rows contains JO123 and that is the row I need to show FFFBBB.  Besides, the special table indicates that the row = JO123 is the only one with the code FFFBBB.

Comment: You were joining on the wrong columns. I've updated the answer.